$business->save(); is not working and not giving error "Laravel"
I'm having an issue adding a store record to the stores table in the database. When I use $business->save(); it's not working and not giving me any error.
stores table migration:
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('businessName')->unique();
            $table->string('businessOwner');
            $table->string('businessCR')->unique();
            $table->string('businessAddress');
            $table->integer('blockNumber');
            $table->string('googleMap');
            $table->string('businessLogo');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stores');
    }
};

Store model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Store extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $fillable = [
        'businessName', 
        'businessOwner', 
        'businessCR', 
        'businessAddress', 
        'blockNumber', 
        'googleMap', 
        'businessLogo'
    ];
}

addStoreController.php controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Store;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


class addStoreController extends Controller
{
    public function addStores(Request $request)
    {

        //validation
        $request->validate([
        'businessName' => ['required', 'string', 'min=2', 'max:40', Rule::unique('stores', 'businessName')->ignore($request->id),],
        'businessOwner' => 'required|string|max:30',
        'businessCR' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9-]{1,10}$/',
        'businessAddress' => 'required|string|min=2|max:30',
        'blockNumber' => 'required|integer|min=1|max:4',
        'googleMap' => 'required|regex:/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com\/maps\/.+$/',
        'businessLogo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:20480',
        ]);

        // save the business
        $business = new Store;
        $business->businessName = $request->businessName;
        $business->businessOwner = $request->businessOwner;
        $business->businessCR = $request->businessCR;
        $business->businessAddress = $request->businessAddress;
        $business->blockNumber = $request->blockNumber;
        $business->googleMap = $request->googleMap;
        $business->businessLogo = $request->businessLogo;
        $business->save();
        
        // Fetch all business stores from the database
        $business = Store::all();
        return view('admin.view_stores', ['Store' => $business])->with('success, store added successfully.');
    }

    public function viewStores()
    {
       $business = Store::all();
       return view('admin.view_stores', ['Store' => $business]);
    }
}

web.php
Route::get('/addStores', function () {
    return view('admin/addStores');
});

Route::post('/admin/addStores', [addStoreController::class, 'addStore']);

addStores.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Add Store</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="addStore">
        <h2>Add Store</h2>

        <form id="addStores" action="/addStores"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <p>Business name:<input name="businessName" type="text" placeholder="Business name"></p>
        <p>Business Owner:<input name="businessOwner" type="text" placeholder="Business Owner"></p>
        <p>Business CR:<input name="businessCR" type="text" placeholder="Business CR"></p>
        <p>Business Address:<input name="businessAddress" type="text" placeholder="Business Address"></p>
        <p>Business Block Number:<input name="blockNumber" type="text" placeholder="Business Block Number"></p>
        <p>Google Map:<input name="googleMap" type="text" placeholder="Google Map"></p>
        <p>Business Logo:<input name="businessLogo" type="file" placeholder="Business Logo"></p>
        <button type="submit">Add Store</button>
        
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

I expected that the store would be added to the database when I clicked the submit button.

Are you getting any specific error ?Have you imported App\Http\Controllers\addStoreController to the top of the web.php file  and App\Models\Store to the top of the Controller?

yes I have imported App\Http\Controllers\addStoreController to web.php but as an error I didnt get any arror when I cklick on submit button the page just like it refresh

I believe that there are multiple things going wrong here. You should add some errors to let us know what it is.
Try fixing the following issues first:

The forms points to /addStores, but the route is registered under /admin/addStores
The $request->validate(...) call returns an array of validated values which you don't use
You call $request->... to try to retrieve values, which doesn't work. You should retrieve them from the data returned by the validate call (eg. $data = $request->validate(...); $business->businessName = $data['businessName'];.


@73moood1 , add method="POST" to the <form> tag

when I add method="POST" I got this error: The POST method is not supported for route addStores. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

@73moood1, that is because in the form action you have pointed this /addStores which is defined in your route as GET, you need to change it into /admin/addStores as per your web.php route defination

ok I will fix it and I will try to add stor to database

Your code has several issues that need addressing.

You need to ensure the route in your form matches the route in your
web.php file.

The form should have the method set to POST.

Validation rule syntax min=2 should be min:2.

You need to handle the file upload properly in the controller.


Update your Controller addStoreController.php to AddStoreController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Store;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class AddStoreController extends Controller
{
    public function addStores(Request $request)
    {
        // validation
        $request->validate([
            'businessName' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:40', Rule::unique('stores', 'businessName')->ignore($request->id)],
            'businessOwner' => 'required|string|max:30',
            'businessCR' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9-]{1,10}$/',
            'businessAddress' => 'required|string|min:2|max:30',
            'blockNumber' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:4',
            'googleMap' => 'required|regex:/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com\/maps\/.+$/',
            'businessLogo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:20480',
        ]);

        // save the business
        $business = new Store;
        $business->businessName = $request->businessName;
        $business->businessOwner = $request->businessOwner;
        $business->businessCR = $request->businessCR;
        $business->businessAddress = $request->businessAddress;
        $business->blockNumber = $request->blockNumber;
        $business->googleMap = $request->googleMap;

        // Handle file upload
        if ($request->hasFile('businessLogo')) {
            $file = $request->file('businessLogo');
            $filePath = $file->store('logos', 'public');
            $business->businessLogo = $filePath;
        }

        $business->save();

        // Fetch all business stores from the database
        $business = Store::all();
        return view('admin.view_stores', ['Store' => $business])->with('success', 'Store added successfully.');
    }

    public function viewStores()
    {
        $business = Store::all();
        return view('admin.view_stores', ['Store' => $business]);
    }
}

Update Your Blade File addStore.blade.php
<form id="addStores" action="/admin/addStores" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    
    <p>Business name: <input name="businessName" type="text" placeholder="Business name"></p>
    <p>Business Owner: <input name="businessOwner" type="text" placeholder="Business Owner"></p>
    <p>Business CR: <input name="businessCR" type="text" placeholder="Business CR"></p>
    <p>Business Address: <input name="businessAddress" type="text" placeholder="Business Address"></p>
    <p>Business Block Number: <input name="blockNumber" type="text" placeholder="Business Block Number"></p>
    <p>Google Map: <input name="googleMap" type="text" placeholder="Google Map"></p>
    <p>Business Logo: <input name="businessLogo" type="file"></p>
    <button type="submit">Add Store</button>
</form>

Update your Routes web.php
use App\Http\Controllers\AddStoreController;

Route::post('/admin/addStores', [AddStoreController::class, 'addStores']);

These changes should resolve your issue.

Controllers should be in PascalCase/CapitalCase.
They should be in singular case, no spacing between words, and end with "Controller".
Also, each word should be capitalised (i.e. AddStoreController, not addStoreController).
